# Electron-dl Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am using [electron-dl](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-dl) to download a file but I cant seem to make it work.
I did almost exactly same as defined in docs but i dont know what is wrong.

**Error:**

I get the following error on main process

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at EventEmitter.ipcMain.on ( \electron-dl-test\main.js:24:7)
```

**How to reproduce (setup):**

1. use repo: https://github.com/mafar/electron-dl-test
2. `npm install` and then `npm start`

**main.js:**

```
  ipcMain.on('download', (ev, args) => {
    download(BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), args.url, args.properties)
      .then(dl => console.log(dl.getSavePath()))
      .catch(console.error);
  })
```

**index.html as renderer:**

```
  document.getElementById("download-file").onclick = function () {
    //
    var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
    ipcRenderer.send('download', {
      url: 'https://textfiles.com/100/ad.txt',
      properties: {
        saveAs: true,
        directory: 'C:\\'
      }
    });
    //
  };
```

**Preview:**
[image]

Comment: No this is how a SO question should be asked!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `download` function is part of an object exported by `electron-dl`. You need to destructure (ES6) or reference it directly (ES5) when requiring the module:

```
const { download } = require("electron-dl") // ES6
```

or

```
var download = require("electron-dl").download // ES5
```